# Symfony2: where to put "pre-set" and "post-get" entity methods?

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine, entity

I have three different entity attributes which have to be "pre-parsed" before they get saved in the datebase.
Same attributes have to be "post-parsed" before being shown to users.

There are several different controllers actions which are setting/getting these attributes. Currently I preparse/postparse this attributes basicly in every of these methods.

How should I handle this? I was thinking about putting it directly into entity but that is not the place for that. Especially because I need the same pre-parse functions in a few entities.

Basically these function has to run before every setter and getter call.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html (pre-parsed: prePersist, preUpdate, post-parsed: postLoad)

Comment: thanks. i used events

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Data Transformers - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

**UPDATE:**

Another, and probably the most appropriate, method would be to use Doctrine `EventListener` or `EventSubscriber`.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

In your case, you need to listen/subscribe to `prePersist`, `preUpdate`, and `postLoad` events.

Comment: useful but not practical for me if data is not comming from a form or if I don't use forms.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a t4 template that generates the model code, then it's relatively easy to change property setters/getters to do the data pre and post-processing.